# Combobox SelectedIndex not being set when using list IndexOf

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I'm creating a combobox programmatically like this:

```
var cbo = new ComboBox {
    DataSource = mylist,
    SelectedIndex = mylist.IndexOf(myvalue)
};
```

I'm not setting `ValueMember` so that the value will be the object itself. When I do the above I get the following exception on the `SelectionIndex` line:

> InvalidArgument=Value of '3' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'. Parameter name: SelectedIndex

Is it because the combobox is still being created and therefore the `DataSource` is  still not populated? If yes, what's the correct way to set the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databiding will not work until after the control becomes visible. So you need to change your code to:

```
var mylist = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).ToList();
var myvalue = 2;
var cbo = new ComboBox();
cbo.HandleCreated += (obj, args) =>
{
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        cbo.DataSource = mylist;
        cbo.SelectedIndex = mylist.IndexOf(myvalue);
    }));
};
this.Controls.Add(cbo);
```

Then as soon as the control becomes visible, the initialization code will run and `ComboBox` will be populated by data source items and its selected index will be set as expected.

Comment: I changed the way that I use `HandleCreated` event for [these reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53927091/3110834). As an alternative, you can also rely on `VisibleChanged` without using `BeginInvoke`.