# Why is the combobox doubling its items when being created?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I'm creating a combobox programmatically as follows:

```
var cbo = new ComboBox();
cbo.HandleCreated += (s, e) =>
{
    cbo.DataSource = mylist;
};
```

When I do the above, the combobox displays double the items contained in the list. However, when I do the following, the combobox displays the correct number of items:

```
var cbo = new ComboBox() {
    DataSource = mylist
};
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Reason

> The `HandleCreated` raises just once. the problem is something else, it's because of the way that `OnHandleCreated` and data-binding has implemented in `ComboBox`.

This is how [`OnHandleCreated`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox.cs,ed3e8a2e872d1a5e) method of the `ComboBox` works:

- It first raise `HandleCreated` event. (Keep in mind, `IsHandleCreated` is true at this point.)
- Then for each item in `Items` collection of the control, sends a [`CB_ADDSTRING`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox.cs,9ad9da365dfce2ec) 
  native message to add the item to native combo box.

And this is how setting `DataSource` works:

- For each item in `DataSource`, it first [adds](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox.cs,d1dc97a908cbfd12) the item to `Items` collection, then checks if `IsHandleCreated` is true, sends a `CB_ADDSTRING` 
  native message to add the item to native combo box.

So when you set `DataSource` in `HandleCreated` event, for each item it sends `CB_ADDSTRING` native message twice.

That's why you see items twice in the drop-down and at the same time `Items.Count` shows correct count. Also it you click on additional item (the last half of the items) you will receive an index out of range exception.

## Solution

To solve the problem, you can use either of the following optoins:

1. You can delay the the `HandleCreated` event code execution by using `BeginInvoke`
2. As another option you can rely on `VisibleChanged` event.

**Option 1 - HandleCreated + BeginInvoke**

```
var mylist = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).ToList();
var myvalue = 2;
var cbo = new ComboBox();
cbo.HandleCreated += (obj, args) =>
{
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        cbo.DataSource = mylist;
        cbo.SelectedIndex = mylist.IndexOf(myvalue);
    }));
};
this.Controls.Add(cbo);
```

**Option 2 - VisibleChanged**

```
var mylist = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).ToList();
var myvalue = 2;
var cbo = new ComboBox();
cbo.VisibleChanged+= (obj, args) =>
{
    cbo.DataSource = mylist;
    cbo.SelectedIndex = mylist.IndexOf(myvalue);
};
this.Controls.Add(cbo);
```

Comment: Click on links in answer to see the related piece of source code of `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 3):

This code duplicates the record, because on your initialization of combobox it will hit the event **HandleCreated** which will add your list to the combobox.  Then after finishing the initialization, the execution of the code will hit the event **HandleCreated** again since the first one that execute that event is from initialization, and the second one is from the run time execution itself.

```
var cbo = new ComboBox(); //initialization
//below this comment is the event
    cbo.HandleCreated += (s, e) =>
    {
        cbo.DataSource = mylist;
    };
```

P.S.

There's a better way on populating comboboxes in C# WinForms; every control (combobox, textbox, etc.) have their different events.  You can check on that first rather than creating your event.

Comment: Do you mean if you put a breakpoint inside the event, it will hit the breakpoint twice? Or as a simple example, do you mean `cbo.HandleCreated += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show("!");` will cause two message boxes? Have you tried that? *Give it a try!*

Comment: I posted the real reason and the solution.